# Auto Updating a column in SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

We are developing a sales app for an assignment in class and there's a Payments table in it with the columns Pay_ID, Invoice_ID, Total_Amount, Received, Balance and Pay_Status. The Pay_Status should be automatically updated to "complete" or "pending" depending on the condition if Total_Amount has been paid or not. How do I create a trigger for this? All columns has been set to varchar(50)
Thanks in Advance for replying

Comment: can You change definition of column or it has to stay as varchar(50) with trigger? Cause You could use formula for that.

Comment: i provided an aswer for that.

Comment: @Whencesoever Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it's computed definition to :

```
(case when [TotalAmount]=[Received] then 'Complete' else 'Pending' end)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use computed columns with "case" statement.
Look here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/

Comment: Thank You, that was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
CREATE TRIGGER tx_UpdatePayStatus
ON Payments
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT TotalAmount FROM Payments) <> (SELECT Received FROM Payments) 
UPDATE Payments
SET Pay_Status = 'Pending'
ELSE 
UPDATE Payments
SET Pay_Status = 'Complete'
END
```